# call some code in file and than in static block Magento

Tags: file, magento, call

Hi i have a code which select the particular select attribute value of a product

```
<?php $attribute_value = $_product->getAttributeText('highligted_features');
print_r($attribute_value);
?>
```

> when i am using this in view file it works properly
>
> but when i place this code in a different file and call that file in
>   static block

and

> than when i call that block in file it gives 500 internal server error

.

when i

Comment: Maybe the `$_product` variable is not defined when you use it a separate template.

Comment: but i am calling that file again oo view,phml file

Comment: Maybe you should post the full code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Check attribute  is not  available   in `used in Product list` attribute setting .Thus you cannot getting in other pages,If you using catalog product flat then flat table is not include `highligted_features` attribute in it columns